# Talend Open Studio accept license

Tags: talend

I'm installing Talend Open Studio 7.3 and clicking on "I accept" button but nothing happens. Has anyone met this problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your JDK version ?
You need at least 1.8.

According to this [post](https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00007vCmMLCA0/cannot-accept-license-agreement-after-installing-talend-731-on-macos-10153-catalina?language=en_US) on the Talend Community, it's possible that if you are not using a supported JDK version, the acceptance of license don't work.

Answer (score 0):

For windows user, you can set the JAVA enviroment by specifying it on shortcut target. For example as below. Just use `-vm <your JDK BIN location`

Make sure match with requirement [example here for 7.3 talend](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/installation-guide-windows/compatible-operating-systems). I could't find 7.1 but you can tried with 1.7 or 1.8 JDK.

[image]

Change the target :

```
"C:\Talent\TOS_DI-Win32-20200219_1130-V7.3.1\TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin"
```